# Disable ontouch listener while the gif animation is playing

Tags: android, animation, webview

I want to disable on touch listener when the animation is being played. I have used WebView for this and the animation is running successfully. But the problem is until and unless 1 loop is completed I don't want to enable the touch listener. After a loop is completed I want to enable the touch listener so that the loop will be played again. I am using on touch motion event but unable to do what i need.

```
GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView(this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");
setContentView(view);

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
   if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
       // view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif"); 
       GIFView view1 = new GIFView (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");
       setContentView(view1); 
       view1.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }
   return true; 
}
```

Comment: simple `return false;` in `onTouch()` method

Comment: @SilentKiller, `return true;` is the correct answer.

Comment: but i want to disable the touch when the animation loop is playing only till the animation has completed its single loop and again enable the touch when the animation is stopped.

Comment: @user2652394 read requirement clearly. question is about to disable on touch listener when the animation is being played

Comment: Yes, i DID read the requirement, and if you want to DISABLE the `onTouch`, just `return true;`. Here is the JavaDoc for the method: "Return true if you have consumed the event, false if you haven't. The default implementation always returns false.". Back to the case, @Meghs, let the view implement an `OnTouchListener` ( return true inside the `onTouch`) when you start the animation. Implement another `OnTouchListener` (return false inside the `onTouch`) when the animation stops. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I am not using start and stop method.. Here is my code.        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
   //view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");
   
    GIFView view1 = new GIFView
         (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");
       
        setContentView(view1);
        
        view1.setOnTouchListener(this);
       
       
  }
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to keep a flag variable whether animation is on or it is stopped.

```
public boolean isAnimationOn = false;
```

make this variable `true` when animation starts and `false` at animation finish.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if (isAnimationOn)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
   
   
   if (loaded){
    
   
    GIFView view1 = new GIFView
         (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");
       
        setContentView(view1);
        
        view1.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }
   else
    return false;
       
  }
  return true;
 }   I kept the loaded value false at first. But it is not working.

Comment: I don't want the touch to be activated when the animation is playing, after the animation i want to enable the touch.

Comment: Same is the thing I am doing, but unfortunately it isn't working. :(

Comment: try to debug and check what you got in touch event.?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to implement that is add transparent layout over it (add it in your xml fill parent height and width).

in animation start

```
transaparentlayout.setClickabe(true);
```

in animation end

```
transaparentlayout.setClickabe(false);
```

very simple.